# Javascript: how to stop the click event queuing?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent

The following code works fine the only problem is that the click event get queued like for example the `setTimeout` gets called for each click and the popup appears multiple times. How to make the popup appear only when user clicks and to ensure that gap between each popup is lets say 4 seconds

```
var showpopup = 1;
var check = true;
var seconds = 4000;             // change the frequency here current frequency = 2 seconds
var url = "https://www.fb.com"; // change the url here
var strWindowFeatures = "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,width=" +screen.width 
                         + ",height=" +screen.height;
function popup (event)
{   
     event.stopPropagation();
     if (showpopup === 1)
     {
          //if 
(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Windows 
Phone|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i))
          //{
                if (check == true)
                {
                      window.open(url , '_blank' , strWindowFeatures);
                      showpopup++;
                      check = false;
                }
          //}
     }
     else
     {
         setTimeout(checkValue, seconds);   
     }
}

function checkValue ()
{
    showpopup = 1;
    check = true;
}

window.onclick = popup(event);
```

Comment: I would have thought that `window.onclick = popup(event);` doesn't set the click handler, because you are setting the return value of (calling popup with an empty event parameter) to handle clicks, rather than setting the function itself, as in `window.onclick = popup;`

Comment: Sorry thats my mistake posted the old version didnt check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called *function throttling* :

```
function throttle(func){
  var timeout=null;
  return function(...args){
    if(!timeout) func(...args), timeout=setTimeout(_=>timeout=null,4000);//if were not waiting, execute the function and start waiting
  }
}
```

So you can do

```
var alert=throttle(window.alert);

alert("Wohoo!");
alert("Never executed!");
```

In your case it would be:

```
window.onclick = throttle(popup);
```

---

My Syntax is maybe a bit complicated (ES6), so lets explain it a bit:

```
return function(...args){
```

return a new function that stores all arguments in the args Array ( So that we can pass it to our inner function)

```
    if(!timeout)
```

If theres no Timeout

```
func(...args),
```

call the function, passing our args array as parameters ( called spread operator)

```
timeout=setTimeout(...,4000)
```

set our timeout to execute after 4000 to execute the following:

```
_=>timeout=null
```

When the timeout finishes, reset the timeout and wait for the next function call...

Comment: is there any way to stop queuing the click events without using this throttle function

Comment: @Alien128 yes shure. You can apply the principle used there however you want. However, through this, your code is really readable

Answer (score 0):

Lodash has a [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle) function for this.

```
_.throttle(func, [wait=0], [options={}])
```

Comment: [wait=0] is probably bad syntax, and embedding a whole framework for just one function isnt really neccessary

Comment: @Jonasw [wait=0] shows that the default value is 0. Lodash has lots of functions which makes things easier, so it is a choice...

Comment: @hackio can you elaborate

Answer (score 0):

The following code solves the problem without using throttle

// JavaScript Document

```
var showpopup = 1;
var check = true;
var seconds = 4000;             // change the frequency here current frequency = 2 seconds
var url = "https://www.fb.com"; // change the url here
var strWindowFeatures = "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=0,left=0,width=" +screen.width + ",height=" +screen.height;

function popup ()
{   
    if (check === false)
    {   
         return;
    } 
    else if (showpopup === 1)
    {
         if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Windows Phone|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i))
         {
              if (check == true)
              {
                    window.open(url , '_blank' , strWindowFeatures);
                    showpopup++;
                    check = false;
                    setTimeout(checkValue , seconds);
              }
         }
    }
}

function checkValue ()
{
     showpopup = 1;
     check = true;
}

window.onclick = popup;
```