# Set a minimal time interval between functions calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, throttling, debouncing

I have a piece of code as follows. It reacts to the change of the input field by running `treat`:

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cebidadaya/1/edit?html,output)

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="text"></input>
    <div id="console"></div>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('app', []);
      app.controller('Ctrl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.$watch('text', function (newValue, oldValue) {
          treat(newValue);
        }, false)
      }])

      function treat(x) {
        debug(x)
      }

      function debug(msg) {
        document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += msg + "<br/>";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to do something special: I want to set a minimal interval (say `500 ms`) between 2 `treat`. So if another `treat` is supposed to run very shortly after a `treat`, I want it to wait a little bit; if the time interval between 2 `treat` is larger than `500 ms`, they could run one after another as normal (I don't want to add a `500 ms` on top of that).

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: how to stop the click event queuing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44289889/javascript-how-to-stop-the-click-event-queuing)

Comment: ng-options can do that can't it? otherwise what you're describing is called a throttle, not a debounce. The initial action happens immediately, then any subsequent actions can't happen more than once per interval.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$watch` use the [ng-change directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) and to throttle the number of calls to the `treat` function, use the `debounce` property of the [ng-model-options directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions):

```
<input type="text" name="userName"
       ng-model="user.name"
       ng-change="treat()"
       ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
```

The above example waits one second between updates of the model and calls to the `treat` function.

> ## Debouncing model updates with `ng-model-options`
>
> The `debounce` property allows you to specify a debouncing delay so that the actual update only takes place when a timer expires; this timer will be reset after another change takes place.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-model-options API Reference (Debouncing)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#triggering-and-debouncing-model-updates)

## [The DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/EfoCOtR2Cbfz3kBXfJwZ?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('optionsExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = { name: 'say' };
  $scope.updates = 0;
  $scope.treat = function() {
    $scope.updates++;
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="optionsExample">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="userForm">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="userName"
           ng-model="user.name"
           ng-change="treat()"
           ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
    <button ng-click="userForm.userName.$rollbackViewValue(); user.name=''">Clear</button><br />
  </form>
  <pre>user.name = <span ng-bind="user.name"></span></pre>
  <pre>Number of calls to treat() = {{updates}}</pre>
</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you... But I think I want to catch every single change, and just delay their corresponding `treat` if two `treat` are too close...

Comment: I will leave this answer here for other readers who may find it useful.

Answer (score -1):

You could implement a qeue were one element is taken out and executed every 500ms :

```
var qeue=[];
function treat(x) {
   qeue.unshift(x);
}
setInterval(function(){
 if(qeue.length){
   debug(qeue.pop())
 }
},500);
```

If you want to stop if the qeue is empty:

```
var qeue=[];
function treat(x) {
   qeue.unshift(x);
}
(function next(){
 if(qeue.length){
   debug(qeue.pop());
   setTimeout(next,500);
 }else{
  qeue.unshift=function(x){
    qeue=[x];
    next();
   };
 }
})();
```