# Why does the frequency of my received websockets sometimes equal zero?

Tags: javascript, time, websocket

Im reciving websocket messages on my webpage, and i'm trying to calculate the frequency at which they are received. I do this like so:

```
let startTime = new Date();
            ws.onmessage = function (evt)
                {

                prevData = recivedData;
                var receivedMsg = evt.data;

                recivedData = JSON.parse(receivedMsg);

                const endTime = new Date();
                const timeDif = endTime - startTime;
                startTime = endTime;
                console.log(timeDif)
                }
```

When I take a look at the console to see what it has printed, I see that the frequency is mostly around 60 ms (as expected). Although, every fourth time or so, it will be 0 ms, I find this unlikely and I cant find what is causing it. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: The underlying TCP socket may be buffering multiple messages in a single packet if the messages are small enough and sent close to the same time, in order to conserve bandwidth

Comment: @Patrick Roberts, so how do I get around this? Send them less frequently? They are being sent around 20 times per second on the server.

Comment: Maybe because of the work of the event loop. At some moment there are more than one events in the queue.

Comment: @AlbertS, you are probably right, but how could I get around it?

Comment: Try to use async-await as onmessage event handler

Comment: @AlbertS, Along with this message handler, I have a loop function (not in the code I posted), would I have to change `function loop(now)` to `async function loop(now)`?

Comment: I think you can. I use a while loop inside async-await

Answer (score 0):

```
ws.onmessage = async () => {
    const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    await wait(50); // await between executions
    // do your code 
}
```

Update:

See this sample code below. You said that you have some loop function. Maybe it will be helpful you if you have access to the event queue every cycle and never have more than one event in the queue.

```
let done = false;

setTimeout(() => {
  done = true
}, 5);

const eventLoopQueue = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => 
    setImmediate(() => {
      console.log('event loop');
      resolve();
    })
  );
}

const run = async () => {
  while (!done) {
    console.log('loop');
    await eventLoopQueue();
  }
}

run().then(() => console.log('Done'));
```

What happens here. You call eventLoopQueue() function every cycle. This function pushes the callback to the queue by setImmidiate(). The callback is executed right away and anything that is in the queue are going to be executed as well. So every cycle you clear up the queue. And I believe it will help you.

Comment: Sadly this still gives 0, but I have noticed a pattern; In the log, it oscillates from 0 to a regular reading.

Comment: They are invoked at the same time and wait together for 50ms. Ok :)

Comment: "They are invoked at the same time and wait together for 50ms" I don't understand, can you explain more?

Comment: Let me try on my computer. Maybe I was wrong when I said that they were run together without waiting.

Comment: I am sorry. My code above does not work. If you have at some moment multiple messages in the queue event loop will release them all to the call stack where they are called without waiting for each other to be completed.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44289889/javascript-how-to-stop-the-click-event-queuing   or here https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#throttle